# What is the toxicity of titanium alloy body implants?

Tags: dentistry, toxicity, orthopedics, poison, implant

I'm looking for public studies to determine how toxic they are. It should be easy to test intelligence with and without implants.

I have an intramedullary nail. When deciding whether to remove it, I'm assuming its toxic, and looking for proof its not.

If you have studies about multiple alloys, try to order them by what you think is most commonly used.

I did these searches on Google and PubMed:

- toxic titanium implant
- toxicity titanium implant
- brain OR neuro toxic titanium implant

There were no results that quantified how often or how toxic implants are. There is a lot about how they can be toxic.

This study showed CNS dysfunction in a 77 year old male, and brain damage in rats.

[Potential neurotoxicity of titanium implants: Prospective, in-vivo and in-vitro study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34352627/)

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Gosh, I hope it is not too toxic, I have had 8 titanium dental implants for about 15 years. Titanium implants are generally anodized so the body is exposed to titanium oxide, not Ti metal. Bone attaches readily to titanium oxide. It does not bond well the 316 SS the most common implant. Don't know the use rate of Vitallium ( chrome cobalt) .

Comment: Depending on anodization and age, removing the nail after bone has bonded ,I think, could cause local trauma.

Comment: It's impossible to prove something is "not toxic". You can say you don't have evidence it's toxic, you can have evidence that it's unlikely to be more toxic than some threshold, but can never show something is non toxic.